# SLF4J logging issue

Tags: java, logging

I have an issue while logging, when I use logger.info it is not getting logged but when I use logger.warn it is getting logged. I am unable to debug this issue, it would helpful if any suggestions are provided to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

```
   public class MyClass {
    private static final Marker status = MarkerFactory.getMarker("STATUS");
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info(status, "Beginning");
        logger.info("Regular info log");
        logger.warn("Warning");
        logger.info(status, "Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to configure the default log level for your logger. And, the way you **do that** depends on what `Logger` you use. slf4j is a *facade*.

Comment: log4j is the logging system, I apologize for not mentioning earlier, I am new to logging, Thanks for your help @Elliott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SLF4J is itself not a logging system. It's a facade for several logging systems. So you need to look up how to configure logging engine it uses. Like if you have one of the log4j SLF4J modules added, you need to add a proper log4j properties file to the classpath.